# Get full url from shorten url in C#.net

Tags: c#, url

I am developing one application where I need capture basic detail like title, description and images of website based on url provided by user.

But user may be enter www.google.com insted of http://www.google.com but C#.net code failed to retrieve data for "www.google.com" through below code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
```

and found error like "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

So do know any technique to found full url based on shorten url.

for ex. google.com or  www.google.com
Expected output : http://www.google.com or https://www.google.com

PS : I found online web tool (http://urlex.org/) that will return full url based on shorten url

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you can use the `urlex.org` api, but you need a pro account!

Comment: Why use that if you can just use some C# code?

Comment: Patrick is right and you should probably use his method, but if you wanted to try with an API there also seems to be a free one here: http://expandurl.com/api.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UriBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a URL with HTTP as default scheme:

```
UriBuilder urb = new UriBuilder("www.google.com");

Uri uri = urb.Uri;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

string responseString;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

If your URL contains a scheme, it will use that one instead of the default HTTP scheme. I have also used `using` to release all unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 1):

> So do know any technique to found full url based on shorten url.

I may have misunderstood your issue here but can't you just append "http://" if it's missing?

```
string url = "www.google.com";

if (!url.StartsWith("http"))
    url = $"http://{url}";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
     String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This is basically what a web browser does when you don't specify any protocol.